# Cisco ASDM issue "cannot open device"

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

I've just gotten my ASA 5510 set up to run AnyConnect VPN (w/ client). Unfortunately, it appears that I broke whatever allows the ASDM to connect in somewhere during that process. I get a "cannot open device" when I try to connect into the device from my ASDM software for another ASA (5520) device that I have.

Both devices have the same ASDM version. Can someone help me with this issue? Below is a sanitized config.

```
    ip local pool XXXVPNPool x.x.5.1-x.x.5.254 mask 255.255.255.0
asdm image disk0:/asdm-715.bin
no asdm history enable

ldap attribute-map XXXVPN_Att_Map
  map-name  memberOf Group-Policy
  map-value memberOf CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=com XXXVPNGrpPolicy
  map-value memberOf "OU=XXXX Users,DC=xxx,DC=com" XXXVPNGrpPolicy
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa-server XXXX protocol ldap
aaa-server XXXX (inside) host x.x.2.38
 ldap-base-dn DC=xxx,DC=COM
 ldap-scope subtree
 ldap-naming-attribute sAMAccountName
 ldap-login-password *****
 ldap-login-dn CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=COM
 server-type microsoft
 ldap-attribute-map XXXVPN_Att_Map

http server enable 65000

http redirect outside 80

crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint2
 enrollment terminal
 fqdn XXXvpn.xxx.com
 subject-name CN=XXXvpn.xxx.com,O=XXXCompany,C=US,St=XXX,L=XXX
 keypair XXXVPNcert
 crl configure

ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint2 outside
webvpn
 enable inside
 enable outside
 anyconnect-essentials
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.00495-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect profiles XXXVPNclient disk0:/XXXvpnclient.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable

group-policy XXXVPNGrpPolicy internal
group-policy XXXVPNGrpPolicy attributes
 wins-server value x.x.2.38 x.x.1.75
 dns-server value x.x.2.38 x.x.1.75
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value XXXVPN_Split_Tunnel_List
 default-domain value xxx.com
 address-pools value XXXVPNPool
 webvpn
  anyconnect profiles value XXXVPNclient type user

tunnel-group TunnelGroup1 type remote-access
tunnel-group TunnelGroup1 general-attributes
 address-pool XXXVPNPool
 authentication-server-group XXXX
 default-group-policy XXXVPNGrpPolicy
 dhcp-server x.x.2.38
tunnel-group TunnelGroup1 webvpn-attributes
 group-alias XXXVPN enable
```

Comment: After looking at the config more, the line `http redirect outside 80` jumped out at me. Removing this didn't fix anything, I'll reload the ASA after work hours to see if that makes a difference. Any suggestions for modifications or debugging are appreciated.

Comment: Below is the config of a working ASA 5520 I have, I've been combing through it for differences.

Comment: I would've put the config in but apparently it's too long for a comment. Any way around this restriction besides splitting it into small posts?

Comment: Just clarification, I'm attempting to access the ASA via the ASDM software connecting to the inside interface address on port 65000

Comment: More clarification, I can get to the page that allows me to download the device manager via the 65000 port, but I cannot actually connect into the device. Also it shows the wrong version of ASDM. This is after I deleted out any old versions of the ASDM image.

Comment: I'm trying to use Wireshark to troubleshoot this issue but I don't see any SSL communications between my machine and the firewall. What am I missing?

Comment: I figured out why the browser was showing 6.2(1). It was cached. But it was cached on both machines I was testing with. Even after running device launcher and the java asdm, I still wasn't able to connect to the device.

I have versioning set up on my firewalls so right now I'm comparing the configs of the 5510 now, the 5510 a month ago, and the 5520. I'll see what I come up with.

On top of all of this, I'm still confused why I didn't see SSL traffic on my wire capture.

Comment: The SSL traffic is on port 65000 and I've found that on my wireshark capture, I'm not sure what I'm specifically looking for in here though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I followed a link here: https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/49741/asa-pixfwsm-unable-manage-unit-sshtelnetasdm#Unable_to_asdm

And had to add `ssl encryption rc4-md5 rc4-sha1 aes128-sha1 aes256-sha1 3des-sha1`

I checked, this was not in the config a month ago and I was able to connect into the asdm just fine. Something about adding the VPN capability to the device required me to add this line in to get ASDM working.